# why app install count is showing less than app uninstall count in Google developer console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I published a free app in Google play store. From last 9 month around 20k user installed my application. From last few weeks in Developer console "Installs by user" count is showing less number than the count in "Uninstalls by user" section. I am not getting how this can happen . Is it because of some issue in Developer console or my understanding about those two terms are wrong?. Please help me to figure out this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google counts only **one installation per User maximum**. But if one User installs your App many times, the **uninstalls keep going up** while the installs stay at 1.

[How exactly do google count app downloads?](https://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/05/16/billions-how-exactly-do-apple-and-google-count-app-downloads/#.tnw_lw35hM8R)